# count parent with all drill down child

Tags: mysql

I have table with structure

```
ID  full_name   Recommended_By  Direction
1   Name1            0             None
2   Name2            1             Left
3   Name3            1             Right
4   Name4            2             Left
5   Name5            3             Left
6   Name6            2             Right
```

i need to know the count of parent with drown line of all his child
example ID ( 1) count is 5    3 left and 2 right

Comment: MySQL doesn't support recursive functions, so it is not well suited to the adjacency list model of storing hierarchical data. You ought to consider restructuring your data to use either nested sets or a transitive closure table.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/192462/623041) for more information.

Comment: any other solution, because i already working in mlm with this structure

Comment: @eggyal The answer you link to says that MySQL 8 supports recursive query in fact.

Comment: @rlanvin: That edit was added three weeks ago.  My comment is from over 5 years ago.

Comment: @eggyal Oops I have no idea how I missed that. My apologies.